# How to set socket option IP_DONTFRAG in python?

Tags: python, sockets, setsockopt, ip-protocol

How can I set DONT_FRAGMENT flag in IP header using python sockets?

The following code

```
socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_DONTFRAG, 1)
```

gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'IP_DONTFRAG'
```

Anyone has an idea?

---

```
def create_sender_session(self):
    logging.debug("Create Sender Session")
    if (self.send_ip_ver == 6 or self.resp_ip_ver == 6):
        self.sender_socket = socket.socket(
            socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sender_socket.setsockopt(
            socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_TCLASS, self.tos)
        self.sender_socket.setsockopt(
            socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_UNICAST_HOPS, self.ttl)
    else:
        self.sender_socket = socket.socket(
            socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sender_socket.setsockopt(
            socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TTL, self.ttl)
        self.sender_socket.setsockopt(
            socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_TOS, self.tos)
    self.sender_socket.setsockopt(
        socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.sender_socket.bind((self.send_addr, self.send_port))
    logging.info('Sender started: {}:{}'.format(
        self.send_addr, self.send_port))
```

Comment: *OS*? *Python* version? Also not sure that calling `setsockopt` on `socket.IPPROTO_IP` is correct. `socket.setsockopt`: change the name `socket` to avoid shadowing the module name. Better: put all your code here, as I suspect multiple other errors.

Comment: Linux version 4.4.92-31-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.8.5 (SUSE Linux) )and python 2.7

Comment: FWIW, I'd be interested in an answer for Python 3.6+ on Linux. In C, you can call `setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_DONTFRAG)` on a IPv4 UDP socket (`AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM`) and the OS will set the "don't fragment" bit on outgoing packets. The python `socket` library is supposed to be a close copy of the C interface, but it appears to be missing `IP_DONTFRAG`. Is there a way to set this flag on a (UDP IPv4) socket with the python `socket` library?

Comment: `self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, 10, 2)` used [here](https://github.com/nokia/twampy/blob/master/twampy.py)

Answer (score -1):

It's harder to find documentation for some socket options than for others. **DONTFRAG* seem to be in the latter category. 
Some references:

- [[IBM]: setsockopt() - Set Socket Options](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/ssocko.htm)
- [[FreeBSD]: IP(4)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ip&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE) (**emphasis** is mine):

  > IP_DONTFRAG may be used to set the Don't Fragment flag on IP packets. Currently this option is respected only on [udp(4)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=udp&sektion=4&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE) and raw [ip(4)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ip&sektion=4&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE) sockets, unless the IP_HDRINCL option has been set. **On [tcp(4)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tcp&sektion=4&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE) sockets, the Don't Fragment flag is controlled by the Path MTU Discovery option**. Sending a packet larger than the MTU size of the egress interface, determined by the destination address, returns an EMSGSIZE error.

```bash
(qaic-env) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q049051558]> ~/sopr.sh
### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###

[064bit prompt]> uname -a
Linux cfati-5510-0 5.10.60.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Aug 25 23:20:18 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[064bit prompt]> head -n 2 /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
[064bit prompt]>
[064bit prompt]> python2 -c "import socket;print([e for e in dir(socket) if \"DONTFRAG\" in e])"
['IPV6_DONTFRAG']
```

As a note, *Python 2* is **no longer maintained** ([EndOfLife](https://endoflife.date/python)), although at the time the question was asked, it still was, so will switch to *Python **3***.

```bash
[064bit prompt]> python -c "import socket;print([e for e in dir(socket) if \"DONTFRAG\" in e])"
['IPV6_DONTFRAG']
```

[[Python.Docs]: socket - Low-level networking interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) doesn't mention them. However, only ***IPV6_DONTFRAG*** seems to exist. 
And that isn't specific to *Python*.

```bash
[064bit prompt]> python -c "import socket, sys;print(\"{:s}\n{:s}\n{:d}\n\".format(sys.version, sys.platform, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG))"
3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08)
[GCC 9.3.0]
linux
62

[064bit prompt]> grep -r DONTFRAG /usr/include
/usr/include/linux/in6.h:#define IPV6_DONTFRAG          62
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/in.h:#define IPV6_DONTFRAG           62
```

As *IPV6_DONTFRAG* name states, it's specific for *IPv6* sockets (and it most likely won't work for *IPv4*):

```py
[064bit prompt]> python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import socket
>>>
>>> s6d = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s6d.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG)
0
>>> s6d.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG, 1)
>>> s6d.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG)
1
>>> s6d.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG, 2)
>>> s6d.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG)
1
>>> s6d.close()
>>>
>>> s6s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s6s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG, 1)
>>> s6s.close()
>>>
>>> s4d = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s4d.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported
>>> s4d.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 92] Protocol not available
>>>
>>> s4d.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 92] Protocol not available
>>> s4d.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 92] Protocol not available
>>> s4d.close()
```

So, for *IPv6* sockets it didn't raise an exception (tests are required to establish whether under the hood it did what is supposed to). 
For *IPv4*, the *Path MTU Discovery* option can be tried ([[SO]: Path MTU Discovery using Socket option - IP_MTU & IP_MTU_DISCOVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29010203/path-mtu-discovery-using-socket-option-ip-mtu-ip-mtu-discover)).

Don't know how relevant it is, but it seems to be working on *Win*:

```py
[cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049051558]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe"
Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import socket
>>>
>>> s4d = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s4d.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG), s4d.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG)
(0, 0)
>>> s4d.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG, 1)
>>> s4d.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG), s4d.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG)
(1, 1)
>>> s4d.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG, 1)
>>> s4d.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG), s4d.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG)
(1, 1)
>>> s4d.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG, 0)
>>> s4d.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG), s4d.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG)
(0, 0)
>>> s4d.close()
>>>
>>> s4s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s4s.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG), s4s.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG)
(1, 1)
>>> s4s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG, 0)
>>> s4s.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG), s4s.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_DONTFRAG)
(0, 0)
>>> s4s.close()
```

Comment: The point of the question is to create an IPv4 UDP socket that sets the `DF` flag on sent packets. None of the stuff you mentioned accomplishes that.